# Blazor component - inline styling

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I've created a simple blazor app that has a slider on top. There is a javascript self executing function that adds some inline css to this slider so it makes its' height the same as window.height. 
I'm adding this javascript file in _Host.cshtml, before closing the body tag.

My issue is that this inline styling isn't applied. I've debugged the javascript code and it gets the correct height, the element on which I want to add the styling is found, the `element.css('height', myHeight)` is being called with the correct value, but in the end there is no style attribute on that element. I've also tried, after the component has been rendered, to remove the script tag from the page and add it again, hoping that it will re-run and then change the height, but no success there as well.

I've created a .NET Core WebApp using that same slider and everything works as expected (I have the style attribute on my element). In this second app I add the script before closing the body tag, in _Layout.cshtml.

Seems preety much the same as the blazor app, but for some reason, on that one doesn't work.
Do you guys have any idea why?

**EDIT:** 
I've found something interesting. In the beginning, the page is loaded correctly, but the component is being reloaded after the app connects to the we socket `Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44361/_blazor?id=cepYgPnJYddq2bHSywwwYw.`. This is when I lose the inline styles.

So how can I stop it from reloading? I guess this is the question.

Comment: Can you share details of what you have tried

Comment: I have. Basically this isn't working on a component: ```element.find('.my-slide').css('height', myHeight);```

Comment: Ok let's try a different question. Why do you need JavaScript just to set some CSS?

Comment: This is a template that I've bought and I want to use it on a Blazor app. It takes the window's height in js and adds the attribute. Basically this is how the creator wanted to work, but for some reason blazor has other plans. I wouldn't want to rewrite the js code so that's why I want it to make it work